# MountainLion printing

Tags: macos, printing

Trying to print on canvas with an Epson Stylus Pro 3800. When I click the PRINT button I get the printer in the Dock for about 5 or 6 seconds and then it disappears and no printing.
 have tried resetting the printer by using that option using CTL +click in Print and Fax and reinstalling it.

Comment: Does anything happen on the printer itself (sans printing)? Does it's led light flash? Have you tried another USB cable?

Comment: Thanks. Nothing occurs on the printer. I have tried another cable but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you run the self test on the printer to make sure it works?

Comment: Thanks Richard. The Users Guide has no reference to Self Test. When I switch it on with the button next to the display (the only on/off option) it starts up normally and after some head cleaning shows Ready with Matt black (as it is programmed to do). The current Epson driver is installed but this is the first time I have tried using it since formatting my HD and installing OSX 10.8.2

Comment: iain: I'm pretty sure all printers have a way to print a page without a computer involved. See if you can find it in the LCD panel or whatever the control system for that printer is. Also, what application(s) are you printing from on the Mac?